# Sampling to find uniques in population

Tags: sampling

The problem I am facing is:

Imagine I have a bag of N marbles, where the value of N is known. In the bag there are k different color marbles. Our goal is to estimate the value of k.

I take a sample of size n. The question is, how can I use this sample data to estimate the value of k?

Comment: Could you specify whether we can make any assumption about the frequencies of the different colours in the bag? Suppose N=1000 and n=10, and all the ten marbles have the same colour. This would suggest that there is only one colour, if all colours must be equally frequent in the bag. But if not, we can't really say anything.

Comment: Unfortunately the only knowledge we have about the distribution of marble colors is what is in our sample.

Comment: Unique still carries the primary meaning of occurring once only, so I recommend the term _distinct_. You have $k$ distinct colo[u]rs. Your specification does not rule out some may occur uniquely.